# How to get a persistent reverse SSH tunnel using autossh?

Tags: linux, ssh, connection

I managed to create a reverse SSH tunnel between a Raspberry Pi 2 and a server of mine (server which has a static IP) and it works fine. The user account I'm using on the server is called "ksproxy" (it's not really a "proxy" but whatever).

Now I'm trying to make `autossh` (from Debian / Raspbian package `autossh`) to work too but I'm not succeeding. I may be close.

(I've changed the real IP here in this question to `37.xxx.yyy.zzz` to not post the server's actual IP)

Here's what works fine: (no autossh)

On the Rpi:

```
rspi@antlia:~ $ ssh -N -R 20000:localhost:22 ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz
```

On the server (the one with the static IP):

```
ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz:~$ ssh rspi@localhost -t -p 20000
rspi@localhost's password:
rspi@antlia:~ $
```

So everything works fine: I enter the password and I get a terminal/prompt.

I can even access the Raspberry Pi from my desktop (by first going through the server), doing:

```
ssh -t ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz "ssh rspi@localhost -p 20000"
ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz password:
rspi@localhost's password:
...
rspi@antlia:~
```

It first ask for the server's password, then for the Pi's password and everything is fine.

So far so good.

Now I try the same but this time with autossh:

```
rspi@antlia:~ $ autossh -M 20000 -N -i /home/rspi/.ssh/id_rsa ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz

ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz:~$ ssh rspi@localhost -p 20000
```

This "works" but it's just stuck there, doing nothing.

I tried to "-vvv" the output of the ssh commands but it just shows that nothing is going on.

If I try another port, it fails:

```
ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz:~$ ssh rspi@localhost -p 1234
ssh: connect to host localhost port 1234: Connection refused
```

If I try the correct port (20000) but this time with the `-t` param, same thing: it "works" but I don't get no terminal/prompt.

Here's a the `-vvv` output

```
ksproxy@37.xxx.yyy.zzz:~$ ssh -vvv rspi@localhost -t -p 20000
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 20000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ksproxy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ksproxy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
...
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
```

It's not asking for password, it's not showing any terminal/prompt.

What am I not understanding here or doing wrong?

Note that I don't think it's a firewalling issue as the "non autossh" method works fine (but then I don't get the automatic "always up" / reconnect feature). I'd really like to make autossh work (I know I could find a workaround, like some crontab automatically relaunching my manual SSH tunnel but that'd probably be more brittle than making autossh work).

Comment: btw by googling for similar questions, I ended up here: maybe this is not the most appropriate SE site for such a question? If it's not, where should I be asking this? (it's not specific to the Raspberry, it's not really for ServerFault --or is it?, ...)

Comment: SuperUser is the place.

Comment: @Jajuke: ok thanks a lot, done!

Answer (score 0):

`autossh` with `-N` and neither `-L`, nor `-R` nor any other forwarding will establish a permanent `ssh` connection that indeed does not do very much. you need to give autossh the same (or comparable) arguments.